extract rows with change in consecutive values of a column from pandas dataframe
I am trying to extract the rows where consecutive value changes for a particular column
Ex:
sno A   B
1   a   yes
2   b   yes
3   c   No
4   d   No
5   e   No
6   f   yes
7   g   yes
8   h   yes
9   I   No

Output:
sno A   B
        
2   b   yes
3   c   No
5   e   No
6   f   yes     
8   h   yes
9   I   No

Consecutive column is B, am trying to extract if the value of column B is changed consecutively

Are you saying that the output is what your code (which you forgot to post in your question) is generating or what it should be generating

Why was this closed? "Add details and clarify the problem being solved. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question." What's unclear? The question seems very clear to me, especially with the example output.

Another possible solution:
d = df['B'].shift().ne(df['B']) 
e = ~d & d.shift(-1)
df[e | e.shift()]


Intermediates:
d:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
Name: B, dtype: bool

e:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
Name: B, dtype: bool


Output:
   sno  A    B
1    2  b  yes
2    3  c   No
4    5  e   No
5    6  f  yes
7    8  h  yes
8    9  I   No


If need select only edge values compare by Series.ne with Series.shifted values, parameter fill_value is used for avoid select first or last consecutive row of DataFrame:
m1 = df['B'].ne(df['B'].shift(fill_value=df['B'].iat[0]))
m2 = df['B'].ne(df['B'].shift(-1, fill_value=df['B'].iat[-1]))

out = df[m1 | m2]
print (out)
    sno  A    B
1     2  b  yes
2     3  c   No
4     5  e   No
5     6  f  yes
7     8  h  yes
8     9  I   No

How it working:
print (df.assign(m1=m1, m2=m2))
   sno  A    B     m1     m2
0    1  a  yes  False  False
1    2  b  yes  False   True
2    3  c   No   True  False
3    4  d   No  False  False
4    5  e   No  False   True
5    6  f  yes   True  False
6    7  g  yes  False  False
7    8  h  yes  False   True
8    9  I   No   True  False


A lot of ways to do, yet another solutions with almost the same ideas:
solution 1:
mask = np.full(len(df), False)
index = np.where(df['B'].values[1:] != df['B'].values[:-1])[0]
mask[index] = True
mask[index+1] = True
df[mask]

solution 2:
index = np.where(df['B'].values[1:] != df['B'].values[:-1])[0]
index = np.concatenate((index, index+1))
df[df.index.isin(index)]  # df.iloc[index].sort_index() can be used instead as well

solution 3:
encoded = df.B.astype('category').cat.codes
df[(encoded.diff().abs().fillna(0) + encoded.diff(-1).abs().fillna(0)).astype(bool)]

